# what's the defualt value of GPIO_InitTypeDef

Tags: stm32, gpio, hal

[image]
[image]
I have checked stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.c or .h, but I can't find out by Alternate is 0 defualtly

Alternate is not 0 defualtly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Armandas has explained what the value will be if you do not assign to it.

The legal values that can be assigned to the member `Alternate` are listed under `GPIO_Alternate_function_selection` in the file `stm32f4xx_hal_gpio_ex.h`, for example `GPIO_AF9_TIM12`.

If you are not using alternate function mode, leave the value undefined or set it to zero.

Comment: won't it go wrong if I leave hh.Alternate undefined?it may be any value.magically it was set 0.however, other variables is Intuitively assgiend by unknown value.who initialized hh.Alternate?

Comment: **If** you are not using alternate function mode the library function will not read this member of the struct, so it does not matter if it is never initialized.  If it makes you sleep better at night then set it to zero yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The struct itself does not have a default value. I'm going to assume that you're askign about the value of `hh` as shown in your code.

As your code is currently written, `hh` is a stack variable and is, therefore, uninitialized.

To initialize `hh` to all-zeros, you should write:

```
GPIO_InitTypeDef hh = {0};
```

In a real-world code, you should manually set all the necessary fields of the struct.

See [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization) for more information on struct initialization.

Comment: thank you.But I want to ask why hh.Alternate was assigned by 0.

Comment: @JAMES reading uninitialised variable is undefined behaviour. The value could be anything (including 0) and may change with every call to the function.